# How to find an element in an ArrayList by using a field value of that element?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I am writing a program in Java which accepts user-inputted String in one class.

On a separate class, I have an array-list of class type 'Item' which contains elements of type String (itemName), int, and double. I was wondering if there was a way to either convert the user-inputted String to an object of type 'Item' (I've heard it's difficult), or if there was a way to access the individual String element itemName of the array-list to compare it to the user-inputted String.

**Item.java**

```
public class Item {
    private String name;
    private int monetaryValue;
    private double weight;

    // Getters and Setters
    // ...

    // Other methods
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Your ArrayList holds `Item` but it contains Strings, ints, and doubles?

Comment: It's unclear, could you share the code of `Item` or re-explain what contains the list ?

Comment: It doesnt matter what you heard, but matters what you tried.

Comment: I understand, JosEdu, but I'd like to know how to go about trying it since I've heard that reflection might be needed. If that's what I need to do (or any other method you have in mind) please let me know and I will do further research on it.

Comment: Are you just trying to find the Item from the list that has an itemName that equals the string the user entered?

Comment: Whoever told you that you needed reflection to turn a String into an object of your class `Item` has no clue what they are talking about.

Comment: @MikeB, yup, that's what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not use Reflection here: it's using a bazooka for killing a mosquito. I'd rather use plain Java.

Check this example below:

```
List<Item> myList = new ArrayList<Item>();
String userInputValue;

// * Add some items to myList
// ...

// * Get user input value
// ...

// * Access the array list
int len=myList.size();
for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
    if (myList.get(i).getItemName().equals(userInputValue)) {
        // Do something ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To create an `Item` from user input, you can do:

```
String input1;
String input2;
String input3;

// Assign user input to input1, input2, input3

String itemName = input1;
int data2 = Integer.parseInt(input2);
double data3 = Double.parseDouble(input3);

Item myItem = new Item(itemName, data2, data3);
```

To access elements from array list, you can do:

```
List<Item> items;
String input;

// Populate items

// Assignment user input to "input" variable.

for (Item item : items) {
    if (item.getItemName().equals(input)) {
        // Do something...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can of course build `Item` objects from user input if you define an input format like `[name:string] [i:int] [d:double]` (example : `john 5 3.4`). You then just have to split this String and use Integer.parseInt and Double.parseDouble to parse the two last arguments.